# Vue.js 2 project structure for Multi Page Site

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using Vue 2 to build a multi-page app, using Webpack with CommonsChunkPlugin to separate shared functionality. In the `common.js` bundle I have Vue, some Vue Components, a font loader, and an object with a function to initialize the Vue instance that I export in case a particular page needs to extend that instance. Pages with additional interactivity use that imported function to initialize Vue and pass a mixin as a parameter.

In order to prevent `new Vue` from being called by both `common.js` and another entry point, I set a global variable `window.m` to `0` in `global.js`, increment it in other entry points, and `global.js` only runs `new Vue` if it's still `0`.

This feels pretty hacky, and I'm wondering how I could better set up my project structure.

**webpack.babel.js**

```js
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
 entry: {
  common: './src/js/global.js',
  home: './src/js/home.js',
  imp_single: './src/js/imp_single.js',
  parent_single: './src/js/parent_single.js',
  faq: './src/js/faq.js'
 },
 output: {
  path: __dirname + '/dist/js',
  filename: '[name].bundle.js'
 },
 devtool: 'sourcemap',
 module: {
  rules: [
   { // eslint
    enforce: 'pre',
    test: /\.(vue|js)$/,
    loader: 'eslint-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    options: {
     formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter')
    }
   },
   {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    test: /\.(vue|js)$/,
    query: {
     presets: ['es2015', 'stage-2']
    }
   },
   {
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: {
     loaders: {
      js: 'babel-loader'
     }
    }
   }
  ]
 },
 plugins: [
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
   name: 'common',
   filename: 'common.js',
   minChunks: 0
  }),
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
   compress: {
    warnings: false
   },
   sourceMap: true
  })
 ],
 resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
  modules: [
   path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
   path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
  ],
  alias: {
   vue: 'vue/dist/vue.common.js',
   src: path.resolve(__dirname, '/src'),
   components: path.resolve(__dirname, '/src/components')
  }
 }
}
```

**global.js**

```js
import WebFont from 'webfontloader'
import Vue from 'vue'

// Vue Components
import accordion from './components/accordion'
import dropdown from './components/dropdown'
import progressbar from './components/progressbar'
import quiz from './components/quiz'
import timeline from './components/timeline'

// Setting a global variable to check for other mixins. If there's additional functionality, let the other bundle initialize Vue
window.m = 0

// Disable typography immediately to avoid FOUT
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].classList.value = 'wf-loading'
// Load our fonts
WebFont.load({
  typekit: {
    id: 'xxxxxxx',
    families: ['Calluna', 'Open Sans', 'Bookmania', 'Freight Text Pro']
  },
  classes: false,
  active () {
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].classList.value = 'wf-active'
    setTimeout(function () {
      document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].classList.value = ''
    }, 500)
  }
})

const global = {
  init (mixin = []) {
    new Vue({ // eslint-disable-line no-new
      el: '#sos',
      components: {
        accordion: accordion,
        dropdown: dropdown,
        progressbar: progressbar,
        quiz: quiz,
        timeline: timeline
      },
      data () {
        return {
          hrStatus: false
        }
      },
      methods: {
        helplines () {
          this.hrStatus = !this.hrStatus
        }
      },
      mixins: [mixin]
    })
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // Global Vue, extended by other pages
  if (window.m === 0) {
    global.init()
  }
})

export default global
```

**home.js:**

```js
import sos from './global'

// TODO Find a better way to do this
window.m++

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  sos.init({
    data: {
      forgotText: 'Forgot Password?',
      forgot: false
    },
    methods: {
      who () {
        // Shows the parent/implementer buttons
        this.forgot = !this.forgot
        // Update text
        if (this.forgotText === 'Forgot Password?') {
          this.forgotText = 'Who are you?'
        }
        else {
          this.forgotText = 'Forgot Password?'
        }
      },
      parentFAQ () {
        // Toggle the 'who are you' buttons
        this.who()
        // This relies on the forgot password FAQ being at the top. Might have to find a better way
        if (this.$children[0].open === false) {
          this.$children[0].toggle()
        }
        // Distance from top, then scroll to it
        let top = this.$children[0].$el.offsetTop
        window.scrollBy(0, top)
      }
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: This all looks pretty horrible. You should try the vue-cli to setup the project. https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli

Comment: Indeed, use vue-cli and try the available templates, they have nice and easy to understand and follow structure. The webpack template is great and pretty scalable!